# Selecting data from multiple tables SQL

Tags: sql

I have this SQL tables:

`User_table:
-id_user;
-name;
-(etc);`

`X_table:
-id_x;
-id_user;
-(etc);`

`Z_table:
-id_Z;
-id_user;
-(etc);`

`Y_table:
-id_Y;
-id_user;
-(etc);`

I want to select all data from X,Z,Y tables, what is the correct syntax? Is it possible with more then 2 tables?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Here we try to help to correct code, or people asking questions difficult to resolve even with examples. This is a question easy to resolve, but, this is not a free coding service web, so I suggest you to read [how to ask in S.Overflow](http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow) and [how to do inner join sql w3schools to your specific question](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp). Hope this helps, have a nice day and do your homework on your own.

Comment: (Because your question involves lack of essential knowledge about sql, originated by not reading basics, its getting downvoted)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select more tables you should use 'join' in from...

for example:

```
select U.id_user, X.id_x
from User_table U join X_table X on U.id_user = X.id_user
group by ...
```

Comment: Like this?  `SELECT * FROM User_table INNER JOIN X_table JOIN Y_table JOIN Z_table WHERE X_table.id_user = User_table.id_user AND Y_table.id_user = User_table.id_user AND Z_table.id_user = User_table.id_user´

Answer (score 0):

Part 1 - Joins and Unions

This answer covers:

Part 1
Joining two or more tables using an inner join (See the wikipedia entry for additional info)
How to use a union query
Left and Right Outer Joins (this stackOverflow answer is excellent to describe types of joins)
Intersect queries (and how to reproduce them if your database doesn't support them) - this is a function of SQL-Server (see info) and part of the reason I wrote this whole thing in the first place.
Part 2
Subqueries - what they are, where they can be used and what to watch out for
Cartesian joins AKA - Oh, the misery!
There are a number of ways to retrieve data from multiple tables in a database. In this answer, I will be using ANSI-92 join syntax. This may be different to a number of other tutorials out there which use the older ANSI-89 syntax (and if you are used to 89, may seem much less intuitive - but all I can say is to try it) as it is much easier to understand when the queries start getting more complex. Why use it? Is there a performance gain? The short answer is no, but it is easier to read once you get used to it. It is easier to read queries written by other folks using this syntax.

I am also going to use the concept of a small caryard which has a database to keep track of what cars it has available. The owner has hired you as his IT Computer guy and expects you to be able to drop him the data that he asks for at the drop of a hat.

I have made a number of lookup tables that will be used by the final table. This will give us a reasonable model to work from. To start off, I will be running my queries against an example database that has the following structure. I will try to think of common mistakes that are made when starting out and explain what goes wrong with them - as well as of course showing how to correct them.

The first table is simply a color listing so that we know what colors we have in the car yard.
[pre]

```
mysql> create table colors(id int(3) not null auto_increment primary key, 
    -> color varchar(15), paint varchar(10));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> show columns from colors;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(3)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| color | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| paint | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into colors (color, paint) values ('Red', 'Metallic'), 
    -> ('Green', 'Gloss'), ('Blue', 'Metallic'), 
    -> ('White' 'Gloss'), ('Black' 'Gloss');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from colors;
+----+-------+----------+
| id | color | paint    |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 | Red   | Metallic |
|  2 | Green | Gloss    |
|  3 | Blue  | Metallic |
|  4 | White | Gloss    |
|  5 | Black | Gloss    |
+----+-------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
The brands table identifies the different brands of the cars out caryard could possibly sell.

mysql> create table brands (id int(3) not null auto_increment primary key, 
    -> brand varchar(15));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> show columns from brands;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(3)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| brand | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into brands (brand) values ('Ford'), ('Toyota'), 
    -> ('Nissan'), ('Smart'), ('BMW');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from brands;
+----+--------+
| id | brand  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Ford   |
|  2 | Toyota |
|  3 | Nissan |
|  4 | Smart  |
|  5 | BMW    |
+----+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

[/pre]

The model table will cover off different types of cars, it is going to be simpler for this to use different car types rather than actual car models.

[pre]

```
mysql> create table models (id int(3) not null auto_increment primary key, 
    -> model varchar(15));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> show columns from models;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(3)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| model | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into models (model) values ('Sports'), ('Sedan'), ('4WD'), ('Luxury');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from models;
+----+--------+
| id | model  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Sports |
|  2 | Sedan  |
|  3 | 4WD    |
|  4 | Luxury |
+----+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

[/pre]

And finally, to tie up all these other tables, the table that ties everything together. The ID field is actually the unique lot number used to identify cars.

[pre]

```
mysql> create table cars (id int(3) not null auto_increment primary key, 
    -> color int(3), brand int(3), model int(3));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> show columns from cars;
+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(3) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| color | int(3) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| brand | int(3) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| model | int(3) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into cars (color, brand, model) values (1,2,1), (3,1,2), (5,3,1), 
    -> (4,4,2), (2,2,3), (3,5,4), (4,1,3), (2,2,1), (5,2,3), (4,5,1);
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from cars;
+----+-------+-------+-------+
| id | color | brand | model |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |     1 |     2 |     1 |
|  2 |     3 |     1 |     2 |
|  3 |     5 |     3 |     1 |
|  4 |     4 |     4 |     2 |
|  5 |     2 |     2 |     3 |
|  6 |     3 |     5 |     4 |
|  7 |     4 |     1 |     3 |
|  8 |     2 |     2 |     1 |
|  9 |     5 |     2 |     3 |
| 10 |     4 |     5 |     1 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

[/pre]

This will give us enough data (I hope) to cover off the examples below of different types of joins and also give enough data to make them worthwhile.

So getting into the grit of it, the boss wants to know The IDs of all the sports cars he has.

This is a simple two table join. We have a table that identifies the model and the table with the available stock in it. As you can see, the data in the model column of the cars table relates to the models column of the cars table we have. Now, we know that the models table has an ID of 1 for  Sports so lets write the join.
[pre]

```
select
    ID,
    model
from
    cars
        join models
            on model=ID
```